# enclose html in variable in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

So, I have few html lines in php:

```
function upload_image()
{
 ?>
  <div class="something">       
    <div class="soemthing le">
        <ul class="haha">           
            <div class="sdfd">
                <div class="sdde"></div>
            </div>  
        </ul>           
    </div>
 </div>
<?php
}
```

I am trying to send these data to js via ajax. I am not sure how to enclose everything into one single variable which then i can send it to js.

Could someone show me how to enclose it into a variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest (subjective) is [**Heredoc**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax

```
$string=<<<HTML
<div class="something">       
    <div class="soemthing le">
        <ul class="haha">           
            <div class="sdfd">
                <div class="sdde"></div>
            </div>  
        </ul>           
    </div>
 </div>
HTML;
```

Then you can just echo your string

```
echo $string;   // or return $string as need be
```

This keeps your code clean and also makes you free of any worries about single quotes double quotes etc. Using quotes you always have to escape codes if they are within similar quotes.

That `HTML` is just a marker, it can be anything at all, just that the closing placeholder should have nothing before it on its line, not even a space.

```
$a=<<<TESTING
Yeah that's nice. Heck with those double " or Single ' quotes :P
TESTING;
```

Comment: Thank you awesome new thing ! ==D

Answer (score 1):

You can set this html data in one variable as follow:

```
<?php
    $variable = "";

    $variable .=  '<div class="something">';
    $variable .=  '<div class="soemthing le">';
    $variable .=  '<ul class="haha">';
    $variable .=  '<div class="sdfd">';
    $variable .=  '<div class="sdde"></div>';
    $variable .=  '</div>';
    $variable .=  '</ul>';     
    $variable .=  '</div>';
    $variable .=  '</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mixing code and template (HTML) like this is usually considered bad form. I'd suggest to either:

- use a templating library such as [Mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) to keep your code and your layout separate
- or to use an MVC framework (such as [Laravel](https://laravel.com/)) that helps you build a proper application structure, and which use templates and views out of the box

or, if all of that is too difficult, to at least read in the HTML from an external file, and the put it into a variable, like so

```
<?php 
    function upload_image() {
        $var = file_get_contents(TEMPLATE_DIR . "/upload_image.html");
    }
?>
```

where, at some central point in a configuration file or something, you do

```
<?php
    define('TEMPLATE_DIR', "[[path to template dir]]");
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually end up going this method. Thank you =)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
function upload_image()
{
  $var = "<div class='something'><div class='soemthing le'><ul class='haha'>           
            <div class='sdfd'><div class='sdde'></div></div></ul></div></div>";
}
```